# Run Macro across all Tabs in Excel File - One line macro code available?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some macro that runs on my current sheet, but I'd like it to run across all tabs in my workbook with the click of a button. Its purpose is to replace all values indicated in f5 with the value in f6, in cells A2:C100.

This is the current code:

```
Sub try()
Range("A2:C100").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=Range("f5").Value, Replacement:=Range("f6").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub

Sub Button4_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the F5 & F6 refer to a fixed sheet Say 'Sheet1' in my example. So despite you may have multiple sheets in your wordbook the Find & Replace always refers to Sheet1!F5 & Sheet1!F6 for example.

Modify the code to following. This will loop thru all Sheets of the current workbook and run the code for each worksheet.  In Sub Try() the sheet is refereed by its codename e.g. `Sheet1.Range` in this example and not the actual name of the sheet.

You can in fact combine everything in a single macro as well.

```
Public Sub try()
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C100").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=Sheet1.Range("f5").Value, Replacement:=Sheet1.Range("f6").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub


Sub Button1_Click()
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    WS.Activate
    Call try
Next WS
End Sub
```

I am not too sure if there can be a one liner code but to get the same feel you can put : to put all statements on a single line. Something like

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets: WS.Activate:    Call try: Next WS
End sub
```